# App deployment to heroku does not show dynamic contents on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi i am new to web development, learning and working on rails 4.2.4 version. I have created a simple blog app that is working absolutely fine on local server, but when i tried to push it on HEROKU only my static are visible on page but not the dynamic contents . where might i be making mistake.please help below is my code for index view.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <tr>     
     <td><%= link_to post.title, post %></td>
        <td><%= post.body %></td>
        <td><%= post.category_id %></td>
        <td><%= post.author_id %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

Comment: Did you add some content to your database yet? Because the data from your development database will not be copied to Heroku, only the schema of your database.

Comment: i have run rake db:migrate

Comment: `db:migrate` keeps your db **schema** up-to-date, not your **data**. You can use a [seed file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) to easily get some data in your database.

Comment: data has been included in the database and is showing in local server, but same is not showing when pushed to heroku

Comment: Again: **data** is **not** pushed from environment to environment. So the data from your local development db is **not** pushed to the production environment. Only the **schema** will change with `rake db:migrate`. Please lookup the difference between the *schema* and the *data* of a database.

Comment: i have set same db for development and production environments. upon looking in my PG admin also, i can seen all my data there. problem seems to lie elsewhere.